# Confirming updates were applied via WSUS

Tags: wsus, patch-management

Is there a way to setup WSUS to e-mail a weekly or monthly report which would indicate the current patch status of each computer under a given WSUS policy?

I'm hoping there is another way to verify that updates are being applied by WSUS, other than having to log in to the WSUS console and browse through all of the clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSUS does have options for sending email notifications. Look in the Options section of the WSUS console.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: WSUS also has reports that show you the failed vs success and needs..

Comment: Just got my first e-mail notification from WSUS. It only provides a general overview. What I'm looking for is an alert that provides the following: 1) confirmation that updates took place on each machine in the policy 2) a listing of machines that were not updated

Comment: Any followup on this, Citizen Chin?  I am just starting to get my hands on WSUS and I am looking for this same functionality.